# What preflight passenger briefing items are required under Part 91?

Tags: faa-regulations, far-91, cfi

I have been taught to use the SAFETY acronym, mostly for checkride purposes. Which of those items are explicitly required (give references please) to include on a PAX brief for non-compensatory pt 91 flight?

My most recent DPE told me that only the seatbelts and the emergency exits are actually required. I found in 91.107(a)(1) the seatbelt requirement but cannot find the emergency exit req. He is right? Are there others?

Note: this scenario is assumed excempt from 91.519.

Comment: I’d say he is right. There is nothing in the AIM or any ACs that I am aware of.  But I always make sure that passengers know how to open the doors. Not a big deal on Cessnas since they work like car doors, but on Pipers with the overhead lock, it could be a problem in an emergency, especially since they only have one door and it is not next to the pilot.

Comment: There are regulations, and then there are best practices.  My personal checklist covers, seat belts, shoulder harnesses, egress (doors, baggage doors, etc.), quiet during TO and LNG, pointing out traffic conflicts or safety concerns, inadvertent window openings, motion sickness procedures, etc.  Should one ever have something go wrong, there will be lots of lawyers and FAA investigators looking to blame the pilot.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can find, the only briefing requirements in part 91 are for large or turbine powered aircraft at [91.519](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/14/91.519) (which you assume exempted from), the one you found along with the seatbelt requirement at [91.107(a)(1)](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/14/91.107), and [91.1035](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/14/91.1035) which deals with fractional ownership aircraft.

An [AOPA article on briefings](https://www.aopa.org/news-and-media/all-news/2015/july/flight-training-magazine/technique--passenger-briefing) also states that:

> Operation of seat belts is the only FAA-required briefing item.

The only references to emergency exits under part 91 is [91.607](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/14/91.607) which pertains to passengers for hire. It only mentions the requirements for the number of exits and does not mention passenger briefing.